# Markov Process for a Shared Channel with Two Users

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory, transition-matrix

***Question*: Consider a communication channel where two users, A and B are sharing. Their arrival rates are $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ and service rates are $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$. Only one user can use the channel at a time and no waiting queues, so the arrival rate is dropped if the channel is busy.**

After thinking about it a while I drew this transition diagram, and I wonder if it's correct?

My logic was that, for user B to enter, the channel should go to a state where user A was served and vise versa. So the state n-1 was when user A accessing the system and n+1 would be user B's.

Also what could be the transition matrix for this scenario?

[image: transition-diagram]

**Update:**
Moved the updated work to an answer.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding your description because I am missing the Markovian dependence here. Are the consecutive arrivals correlated?

Here is what I understand, please correct me: there is an arrival to user i with rate $\lambda_i$. Since you didn't mention any structure to the arrival processes, I'm guessing it is memoryless and basically at any given time-slot arrival to user $i$ is with prob. $\lambda_i$.  If only one arrival happens to user $i$, they get $\mu_i$ units of service. What happens if both users get an arrival? Do they just get a conflict and drop packets?

Comment: What do the states $n-1$, $n$, and $n+1$ represent?  The system model is not clearly described.

Comment: If I were to "reverse-engineer a problem formulation" I would assume this: Continuous time, arrivals are independent Poisson processes, and service times are independent and exponentially distributed. Then a better model is to have states $\{Busy_A, Idle, Busy_B\}$, meaning that at any given time, the channel can either be busy serving a type A job, idle, or busy serving a type B job.

Comment: Hi, the question I extracted from a question paper and that was all the information they have give. From the area in the paper where the question was, I could say that it is a memoryless system and the distributions are both independent exponential process. I guess it's an M/M/1/K system. I have updated the question with a diagram with state suggested by @Michael as it seems to make much sense. :)

Comment: Note that the transition state diagram was drawn by me. I'm not sure if it's correct. Need to figure out..

Comment: Yes, your updated work is correct.  If you like, you can cut-and-paste that work into an answer and then resolve the question by giving it "best answer."   That is standard practice when you solve a problem based on hints. I assume you define your matrix $P$ with respect to the embedded discrete time chain that samples the continuous time chain only at times of state changes.

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you @Michael for pointing me the right path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (1) is the state when A is being served and B (3) is the state when B is being served. Idle (2) is when channel is empty.

[image: updated-diagram]

So I came up with the infinitesimal generator of this process as,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-\mu_A & \mu_A & 0\\            
\lambda_A & -(\lambda_A+\lambda_B) & \lambda_B\\
0 & \mu_B & -\mu_B
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

and the transition matrix as,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P} =\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_{00} = -\upsilon_0 & \gamma_{01} & \gamma_{02}\\
\gamma_{10} & \gamma_{11} = -\upsilon_1 & \gamma_{12}\\
\gamma_{20} & \gamma_{21} & \gamma_{22}=-\upsilon_2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\            
\lambda_A/(\lambda_A+\mu_A) & 0 & \lambda_B/(\lambda_A+\mu_A)\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}